# How can we generate a Request Token in Load Runner and use it in web_add_auto_header

Tags: javascript, header, token, loadrunner

I am using Load runner 12.53 I got the below auto header from the recording:
`web_add_auto_header("requestToken",
        "QatDCtRWnAtkRBXEqwHALSd%2F2T4sfkiOcGGcXfhAxRG%3D"); - always a dynamic value.`

I tried to correlate the value but I didn't get it in response body then I came to know it is generating from client side. Is there any way we can generate the code from load runner script and use it in header.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, find the JavaScript algorithm which is generating the request token and then reproduce that algorithm in your code.  You have a number of paths for this, from execution of the JavaScript to conversion to the language of your virtual user (My preference)